# add comments to a button

Tags: c#, wpf, button, tags

I need to add tags to a button in asp.net using c# language. I need the tag be viewable whenever the mouse is poining the button. I am designing a wpf app. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you tagging it WPF when you actually want ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2):

If this is WPF, I don't think you need a tag as tags are not visible on pointing to the control but the tooltip is.

```
<Button Content="Submit" Tooltip="Click this to submit" 
    Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks guys, it properely works. I call WPF because it is a windows presentation file! and I am using ASP.net for it. Let me know if I am wrong.
thanks anyway

Comment: Please mark it as an answer if the provided solution works for you. I guess Eduardo answered before I did and his answer is more comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're talking about tooltips:

```
<Button Content="Submit">
<Button.ToolTip>
    <ToolTip>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">Submit Request</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Submits the request to the server.</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </ToolTip>
</Button.ToolTip>
```

Comment: I don't think you need a tag as tags are not visible on pointing to the control but the tooltip is.

Comment: I think that Eduardo read the tags - they state WPF, while the question talks about ASP.NET.